# What is this thing? It is hairy mostly a cocoon, and i saw a white worm pop out of it. It is spreading rapidly

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I suspect it is originating from the mud. This has some plastic bits with it. They are spreading all over my walls. I think it is some  kind of cocoon for worm. Should it's rapid growth in terms of number be a matter of concern? found in Bangalore, India,
[image: this is a close up shot. I noticed that white worm popped out after i put some alcohol on it.]

[image: It is sticking on the wall and the grip is very firm]

[image: There are many more]

Answer (score 3):

Bagworms?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagworm_moth
I don't know how destructive individual species are. They probably aren't more than an aesthetic concern.

Comment: Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3o3lIVXANg

Comment: No, it doesn't seem like a bagworm.